# open a file and replace a word using perl

Tags: perl

I want to open a file and replace a word from a file.
My code is attached here.

```
open(my $fh, "<", "pcie_7x_v1_7.v") or die "cannot open <pcie_7x_v1_7.v:$!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  if ($line =~ timescale 1 ns) {
    print $line $msg = "pattern found \n ";
    print "$msg";
    $line =~ s/`timescale 1ns/`timescale 1ps/;
  }
  else {
    $msg = "pattern not found \n ";
    print "$msg";
  }
}
```

File contains pattern `timescale 1ns/1ps`.
My requirement is to replace `timescale 1ns/1ps` to be replaced with `timescale 1ps/1ps`.

## At present else condition occurs always.

Update code after receiving comment:
Hi,
Thanks for the quick solution.
I changed the code accordingly, but the result was not successful.
I have attached the updated code here.
Please suggest me if I missed anything here.

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;

open(my $fh, "<", "pcie_7x_v1_7.v" )
or die "cannot open <pcie_7x_v1_7.v:$!" ;
open( my $fh2, ">", "cie_7x_v1_7.v2")
or die "cannot open <pcie_7x_v1_7.v2:$!" ;

while(my $line = <$fh> )
{

  print $line ;

  if ($_ =~ /timescale\s1ns/ )
  {
   $msg = "pattern found \n " ;
   print "$msg" ;
   $_ =~ s/`timescale 1ns/`timescale 1ps/g ;
  }
  else
  {
   $msg = "pattern not found \n " ;
   print "$msg" ;
  }
  print $fh2 $line ;

  }
  close($fh)  ;
  close($fh2) ;
```

Result:
pattern not found

pattern not found

pattern not found

pattern not found

Regards,

## Binu

3rd update:
       // File       : pcie_7x_v1_7.v
         // Version    : 1.7
          //
          // Description: 7-series solution wrapper : Endpoint for PCI Express
        //
          //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
  //`timescale 1ps/1ps
    `timescale 1ns/1ps

  (* CORE_GENERATION_INFO = "pcie_7x_v1_7,pcie_7x_v1_7,
```

Comment: You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your Perl programs, and indent them so that they is intelligible. It is bad manners to ask for help with your work when you haven't applied these simple precautions.

Comment: This code does not compile. First off, you have not quoted the string `timescale 1 ns` (with a match operator or single/double quotes). Your program would die at this point. Also `print $line $msg = "pattern found \n "` is a nonsense statement. You are trying to use your input string as a file handle, and using an assignment on the same line?? Never, ever post code that you have not tried to run first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a perl oneliner from a command line. No need to write a script.

```
perl -p -i -e "s/`timescale\s1ns/`timescale 1ps/g" pcie_7x_v1_7.v
```

-

However,

If you still want to use the script, you are almost there. You just need to fix a couple errors

```
print $line; #missing 

if ($line =~ /timescale\s1ns/) #made it a real regex, this should match now

$line =~ s/`timescale 1ns/`timescale 1ps/g ; #added g to match all occurences in line
```

after the `if-else` you must print the line to a file again

for example, open a new file for writing (let's call it 'pcie_7x_v1_7.v.2') at the beginning of your script

```
open(my $fh2, ">", "pcie_7x_v1_7.v.2" ) or die "cannot open <pcie_7x_v1_7.v.2:$!" ;
```

then , after the else block just print the line (whether it's changed or not) to the file

```
print $fh2 $line;
```

Don't forget to close the filehandles when you're done

```
close($fh);
close($fh2);
```

**EDIT:**

Your main problem was that you used `$_` for the check, while you had assigned the line to `$line`. So you did `print $line`, but then `if ($_ =~ /timescale/`. That would never work.
I'm copy pasting your script and made a couple corrections and formatted it a little more dense to better fit in the website. I also removed the `if match` check as suggested by TLP and directly did the substitution in the if. It has exactly the same result. This works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh, "<", "pcie_7x_v1_7.v" )
    or die "cannot open <pcie_7x_v1_7.v:$!" ;
open( my $fh2, ">", "pcie_7x_v1_7.v2")
    or die "cannot open >pcie_7x_v1_7.v2:$!" ;

while(my $line = <$fh> ) {
    print $line;
    if ($line =~ s|`timescale 1ns/1ps|`timescale 1ps/1ns|g) {
        print "pattern found and replaced\n ";
    }
    else {
        print "pattern not found \n ";
    }
    print $fh2 $line ;
}
close($fh);
close($fh2);

#now it's finished, just overwrite the old file with the new file
rename "pcie_7x_v1_7.v2", "pcie_7x_v1_7.v";
```

Comment: I want to do this check for a series of files from different folders,so one liner may not be helpful.I just started with one file.

Comment: You forgot to mention that there is no point in checking for `timescale 1ns` first. The substitution happens if it can happen, and it can be used as a boolean to check if it did happen.

Comment: Your one-liner can be written `perl -pi -e 's/timescale\s+1\Kns/ps/g'` if you are using perl version 5.10 or later.

Comment: Getting error for the line whereever $msg is used:Global symbol "$msg" requires explicit package name at timescale.pl line 18. Help requested to solve the error.

Comment: @user3069354 it means you haven't declared variable $msg. Use `my $msg;` at the beginning of your script.  @TLP thanks for the note. You are correct but lets stick to the basics for now (I believe you understand :) ).

Comment: @foibs, Code is not executing "if ($line =~ /timescale\s1ns/ )", alwasy it is going to else condition. File contains a line "`timescale 1ns/1ps" .

Comment: How to search for "`timescale 1ns/1ps"; how to search for "/" ?

Comment: @BRC can you please post some sample data from your file?

Comment: @BLP I rewrote your script and now it works. Notice how I used `|` as the regex delimiter and it searches for "`timescale 1ns/1ps".

Comment: @foibs, Thanks for your modification. This time it worked. File "pcie_7x_v1_7.v2" updated with the expected substitution. But my original file "pcie_7x_v1_7.v" remails the same. for changing the original content I made 3 changes; 1. use File::Copy; 2.open(my $fh, "+<", "pcie_7x_v1_7.v" )
  or die "cannot open <pcie_7x_v1_7.v:$!" ; 3. copy($fh2,$fh) or die "File cannot be copied" ; Result is showing an error: "Filehandle $fh2 opened only for output at /usr/share/perl5/File/Copy.pm line 200, <$fh> line 1793.
File cannot be copied at timescale.pl line 28, <$fh> line 1793." . Please help.

Comment: just rename the new file to replace the old file. I added one line to the end of the script. File copy doesn't work with filehandles, it works with simple filenames

Comment: @foibs, Thanks for your support. I am very glad to received this kind of support in my learning phase. Now my aim is to do this check for more than 20 files in a folder. I will write the code and try.